# How to handle referencing two versions of external library in one Project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll, reference, nuget

Project A references 2 projects - Project B which uses EF 5.x and Project C which uses EF 6.x

[image: Project Flow]

Due to the nature of EF, I believe Project A has to reference each EF version but I can't figure out how to do this with Nuget or otherwise.

Comment: `extern alias` is what you want to google.